# How to analyze memory consumption when running application inside container

Tags: java, docker, memory-management, rx-java2, micronaut

I am running a RxJava-Micronaut with application and sqlite database inside the container. This application is having a scheduled job which process half millions string records from database (it calls other api in the batch of 200 records during that process) . We are loading all these records in one shot using RxJava Flowable and using BackPressure Drop Strategy. There is no OutOfMemoryError.

I am trying to understand memory consumption by container. Container memory limit has been set to 512M.

My Docker file is having below JVM params

```
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms200m -Xmx235m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/data/heapdump.hprof -Dmicronaut.environments=${CONFIG_ENV} -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -jar myapp.jar
```

Here I have Jvm min and max to 200M and 235M respectively.

What here I am looking is to understand all components which is contributing to container memory consumption.

1. When I check the `docker stats` for the container, it shows memory usage around 450M out of 512 even if the schedule job inside docker is not running. How can I check what all is contributing to this memory usage.
   [image]

As suggested I have checked inside the container and found java process is consuming that much memory (439M)

[image]

How to investigate further here. I believe heap dump will show details or memory occupied in heap which in my case max is 235M. What else might be contributing to 437M? How can I check that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: "*How can I check what all is contributing to this memory usage.*" - Jump into the container, locate the process, analyze the memory pages. This it the only way to see with 100% certainty what is going on, although this might be time consuming

Comment: "*On prometheus we are using container_memory_usage_bytes metrics*" - As far as I know, micronaut is mp-compatible. There are more powerful metrics with mp-metrics; we should be able to get metrics for the different memory areas of the JVM. This might be worth exploring.

Comment: "*can container go beyond the allocated memory limit 512M as I have seen few instances in the past on the same porometheus metrics.*" - If the memory limit for the container is set to 512M, then no. k8s will enforce the container memory limit. If the pod exceeds the limit, it will be killed.

Comment: @Turing85 removed the multiple questions